# How to write a macro (average n1 n2 n3...) to compute the average of the numbers

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to use defmacro to compute the average of a list of number. It should run like this:

```
user=> (avg 1 2 3 4 5 6)
3.5
```

My code is:

```
(defmacro ave [& number]
   `(float `(/ `(reduce + ~number) `(count ~number))))
```

but I got an error:

```
**ClassCastException clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.RT.floatCast (RT.java:1262)**
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Just te be clear, this **not** a real case for using a macro, it's a good question about **how** to write one. If you come across this answer later, please don't write macro's unless you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one syntax-quote that wraps the whole expression, and unquote-splicing for your numbers as list argument. Besides that, as either `reduce` and `count` accept a list as argument, I've used `list` to wrap them. So, try:

```
(defmacro ave [& number] 
  `(float(/ (reduce + (list ~@number)) (count (list ~@number)))))
```

That in REPL yields:

```
user=> (ave 1 2 3 4 5 6)
3.5
```

---

**UPDATE**: Based in the error pointed out by [amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625403/amalloy) in comments, this is my second version:

```
(defmacro ave [& number] 
  `(let [ns# (list ~@number)] 
     (float (/ (reduce + ns#) (count ns#)))))
```

My test in the REPL:

```
user=> (ave (do (println "Doing a lot of work...") 1) 2 3 4 5 6)
Doing a lot of work...
3.5
```

Comment: Aside from this being a bad problem to use a macro for at all, your implementation of the macro has the serious problem that it double-evaluates `number`: try it like `(ave (do (println "Doing a lot of work...") 1) 2 3 4 5 6)`, for example.

Comment: @amalloy: You are right. I'm a big newbie with macros. I guess I should use gensym local-binding. Let me try to fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It does work, but what if I change the arguments into a vector, like `ave [1 2 3 4 5 6]`, and I change the code into `(defmacro ave [vector] `, `(float (/ reduce + (~@vector)) (count (~@ vector))))` . But I get an error like passing wrong numbers of arguments. I do not exactly understand why we put the list before ~@. Thanks!

Comment: @XiufenXu That's exactly why this is a bad candidate for being a macro at all. It should just be a function that takes in a list of things.

Comment: @ amalloy I agree with you. I am also a newbie with macros and gensym. I  should finish a task with macros. And I have fixed that taking arguments as a vector. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

As amalloy suggested, the best solution is a function:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as str] )
  (:use tupelo.core))

(defn avg
  "Compute the average of 1 or more vals."
  [& values]
  (when (zero? (count values)) 
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "avg: error - at least 1 value required")))
  (let [total   (apply + values)
        result  (double (/ total (count values))) ]
    result))
```

and it's tests:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core 
        clojure.test 
        tupelo.core))

(deftest t-avg
  (is (thrown? IllegalArgumentException (avg)))
  (is (= 1.0 (avg 1)))
  (is (= 1.5 (avg 1 2)))
  (is (= 2.0 (avg 1 2 3)))
  (is (= 2.5 (avg 1 2 3 4))))
```

Note that the function is more powerful than a macro, as a macro cannot be passed as an argument to a higher-order function (e.g. filter, map, etc).